# Knockout - Display Pivot Data from LINQ in HTML Table

Tags: html, linq, t-sql, knockout.js

In my code, I call a stored procedure. I want the row values of one column in the result(TaskName) to be used as the HTML table columns.

The code I currently have displayed all pivoted data in one cell. The pivot is done in LINQ as entity framework would not read a dynamic SQL query in a SQL sproc.

I have control over each of the below code sections so anything can be updated.

Here is the sproc output...

[image]

And this is how I want the HTML table to look...

[image]

**How do I display the data in the desired format above?**

Here is the LINQ query...

```
var records = from tr in _dbContext.Task_GetParentRecords().AsEnumerable()
                          group tr by tr.EntityCode
                          into grp
                          select new TaskRecordOverviewDTO()
                          {
                              EntityCode = grp.Key,
                              Tasks = grp.Select(t => t.TaskName),
                              StatusFlagName = grp.Select(t => t.OverallStatus)
                          };
```

Below is my HTML, JavaScript, and KnockOut code...

```js
var viewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
   
    // variables   
    self.taskRecordsTEST = ko.observableArray([
    {
        "EntityCode": "DEMO",
        "Tasks": [
            "Cash Process",
            "Positions Process",
            "Trades Process",
            "Addendum Errors"
        ],
        "StatusFlagName": [
            "RED",
            "RED",
            "RED",
            "ORANGE"
        ]
    },
    {
        "EntityCode": "SP00",
        "Tasks": [
            "Cash Process",
            "Positions Process",
            "Trades Process",
            "Addendum Errors"
        ],
        "StatusFlagName": [
            "RED",
            "ORANGE",
            "RED",
            "GREEN"
        ]
    }
]); 
   
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Entity Code</th>
                <!--ko foreach: taskRecordsTEST-->
                <th>
                   <div style="height:50px" data-bind="text: Tasks"></div>
                </th>
                <!--/ko-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: taskRecordsTEST">
            <tr class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled">
                    <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: EntityCode"></td>
                    <td class="ui-state-default" data-bind="text: StatusFlagName"></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v2L1ny8r/9/

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry. Updated.

Comment: Well, that's way too broad. At the very least you need to show one serious attempt to accomplish this yourself _and_ indicate exactly where it failed or where you're stuck.

Comment: The data is merged into one cell header when I need it split into separate cell headers. That's all that is required.

Comment: I think my code does show a serious attempt to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think you can use a with binding along with a foreach.

http://jsfiddle.net/v2L1ny8r/13/

```
  <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Entity Code</th>
     <!--ko with: taskRecordsTest()[0]-->
        <!-- ko foreach: $data.Tasks -->
         <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
        <!--/ko-->
      <!--/ko-->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: taskRecordsTest">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: EntityCode"></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: $data.StatusFlagName -->
          <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
        <!--/ko-->
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```